# Does Anyone Know Why I-Tunes Continues to Install After Uninstalled?

Tags: windows-7

When I bought my son his I-Phone 2 years ago. I made the mistake of putting his I-Tunes account on my computer. It pulled everything off my business computer. Even all my server information for every sever for all online radio stations & more. Everything had to be shut down and recoded. It was uninstalled. However, every time Microsoft does updates it reinstalls. I've tried not just Kaspersky, but Norton Eraser, Malwarebytes. I just don't understand. Any ideas anyone???

Answer (score 1):

When Apple installs iTunes, it installs other applications too. If you only removed iTunes, the other applications remain and still run. One of those applications is their updater software. It will continue to install updated versions of iTunes.

[image]

It is not a virus or malware so the programs you listed won't treat is as such.

Therefore, a complete removal of the package of applications is required. The instructions linked below are from an older post, but still relevant to removing all the applications and files.

[Completely Remove iTunes and Other Apple Software from a Windows Computer](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/23959/completely-remove-itunes-and-other-apple-software-from-a-windows-computer/)

Comment: I think Windows anti-virus software should come with an option: "Treat Apple software as a virus". Check it and it removes it for you.